# ionic Popover content position issue

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-popover

I've implemented a popover with number keys on it using this library https://github.com/alvarowolfx/ng-keypad.
When I click on an input field, the popover appears. But, sometimes the position of content of popover is not correct.
Can you please help me.

Here is my html:

```
<script id="keypad-popover.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-popover-view class="aiv-keypad">
    <ion-content overflow-scroll=false>
        <div class="ios">
            <ng-keypad on-key-pressed='onKeyPressed'>
                <ng-key ng-repeat='key in aivkeys' ng-key-data='key' ng-key-type='keypad.type'>{{key}}</ng-key>
                <!--<ng-key ng-key-type='keypad.type' ng-key-data="keypad.data">{{keypad.data}}</ng-key>-->
            </ng-keypad>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-popover-view>
</script>
```

In controller,

```
$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('keypad-popover.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    backdropClickToClose:false
}).then(function(popover) {
    $scope.keypad_popover = popover;
});
```

Expected,

[image]

Sometimes, this problem occurs,

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've temporarily solved it by adding custom css .aiv-keypad .scroll{transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1)!important;}

Answer (score 0):

While the problem could be described as *overflow scrolling*, the `overflow-scroll=false` attribute you're using on `<ion-content>` means you are *explicitly using Ionic scroll*, which is to use `transform3d()` in CSS to implement scrolling. Usually `overflow-scroll=false` is the default.

If you'd turn `overflow-scroll=true` the element would use "traditional" `overflow-y: auto` CSS rule instead of `transform3d()`. With popovers, this is usually enough to fix the problem you describe.

If not—you can disable element's scrolling altogether with `scroll=false` attribute.